# Get active users by month

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, count, window-functions

Using MySQL, I'm trying to get the number of active users I have in any given month.  I have a table with `ActivationDate` and `TerminationDate` columns, and if the month being counted is after the `ActivationDate` and `TerminationDate` is null, then the user is active and should be counted.  I would like to summarize these amounts by month.  I'm thinking I could just `sum` each side and calculate the total but breaking that down won't give me a running total. I've tried with window functions, but I don't have enough experience with them to know exactly what I'm doing wrong and I'm not certain how to ask the right question.

So for instance, if I have the following data...

```
UserId  ActivationDate  TerminationDate
1  2020-01-01  null
2  2020-01-15  null
3  2020-01-20  2020-01-30
4  2020-02-01  null
5  2020-02-14  2020-02-27
6  2020-02-15  2020-02-28
7  2020-03-02  null
8  2020-03-05  null
9  2020-03-20  2020-03-21
```

I would like my results to be similar to:

```
2020-01  2  (there are 2 active users, since one signed up but cancelled before the end of the month)
2020-02  3  (2 from the previous month, plus 1 that signed up this month and is still active)
2020-03  5  (3 from previous, 2 new, 1 cancellation)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot, then aggregate and sum. In MySQL 8.0.14 or higher, you can use a lateral join:

```
select date_format(x.dt, '%Y-%m-01') as dt_month, 
    sum(sum(cnt)) over(order by date_format(x.dt, '%Y-%m-01')) as cnt_active_users
from mytable t
cross join lateral (
    select t.activationdate as dt, 1 as cnt
    union all select t.terminationdate, -1
) x
where x.dt is not null
group by dt_month
order by dt_month
```

In earlier 8.x versions:

```
select date_format(x.dt, '%Y-%m-01') as dt_month, 
    sum(sum(cnt)) over(order by date_format(x.dt, '%Y-%m-01')) as cnt_active_users
from (
    select activationdate as dt, 1 as cnt from from mytable
    union all select terminationdate, -1 from mytable 
) x
where x.dt is not null
group by dt_month
order by dt_month
```

Comment: Nice one!  Thanks for that.  I'll try it out and run it by my team.  If it's the answer we go with, I'll be sure to mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version of MySQL.  If you're using 8.0, this should work:

```
create table userdates (
    UserId int not null,
    ActivationDate date not null,
    TerminationDate date null
);

insert into userdates (UserId, ActivationDate, TerminationDate)
values
  (1, cast("2020-01-01" as date), null      )
, (2, cast("2020-01-15" as date), null      )
, (3, cast("2020-01-20" as date), cast("2020-01-30" as date))
, (4, cast("2020-02-01" as date), null      )
, (5, cast("2020-02-14" as date), cast("2020-02-27" as date))
, (6, cast("2020-02-15" as date), cast("2020-02-28" as date))
, (7,  cast("2020-03-02" as date), null     )
, (8,  cast("2020-03-05" as date), null     )
, (9,  cast("2020-03-20" as date), cast("2020-03-21" as date))
, (10, cast("2020-07-20" as date), null)
, (11, cast("2019-09-12" as date), cast("2019-09-14" as date));

WITH RECURSIVE d (dt) 
AS (
      SELECT cast("2019-01-01" as date)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT date_add(dt, interval 1 month)
      FROM d 
      WHERE dt < cast("2020-12-01" as date)
    )

select d.dt
, count(distinct ud.UserId) as UserCount
from userdates ud
  right outer join d on d.dt >= date_format(ud.ActivationDate, '%Y-%m-01')
              and (d.dt <= ud.TerminationDate or ud.TerminationDate is null)
group by d.dt;
```